# Estimation with inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $x$, $u$, $w$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ suppose that $u$, $w$ are close:
$$
\| u - w \| < \frac{1}{n}, 
$$
and we have an upper bound for the inner product:
$$
\langle x, u \rangle < 1. 
$$
Is it possible to find an upper bound for the inner product $\langle x, w \rangle$ without using any additional information about $x$, for example $\|x\|$?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz implies
$$|\langle x, u \rangle - \langle x, w \rangle| = |\langle x, u-w\rangle |
\le \|x\| \|u-w\|,$$
so an upper bound for $\langle x, w \rangle$ is $1 + \frac{1}{n} \|x\|$. I think you can show this cannot be improved by finding an example with $u-w$ parallel to $x$ and $\langle x, u \rangle$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose some $u \neq 0$ and $\delta \bot u$ with $\|\delta\| = {1 \over 2n}$ and let $w=u+\delta$, then $\|w-u\| < { 1 \over n}$.

Let $x(t) = {1 \over 2 \|u\|^2} u + t \delta$, note that
$\langle x(t), u \rangle = {1 \over 2}$ for all $t$.

However, $\langle x(t), w \rangle = { 1 \over 2} +t {1 \over (2n)^2}$.

Hence you cannot bound $\langle x, w \rangle$ without more conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot copper.hat , your counterexample is very nice!